# Is there a way to show/hide an element based on existence of a parent class in Tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

Is there a way to tell Tailwind: If a parent has a certain class then show a certain HTML element, if not hide it? Or can this not be done in Tailwind?

```
<body>
  <div class="hidden">Hello</div>
</body>

<body class="show">
  <div class="block">Hello</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 11):

just a quick fyi, all this is now possible in Tailwind 3.

There's a wide range of modifiers you can find here:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

Some examples:

```
<div class="group is-published">
  <div class="hidden group-[.is-published]:block">
    Show only when parent has class "is-published"
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to add other classes when a certain class is present on the same element:

```
<div class="relative [&.active]:opacity-80">
  The class opacity-80 will actually work only when the class "active"
  is present inside the class list of the element
</div>
```

And even very complex stuff:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" class="peer" />
      <div class="hidden peer-[:nth-of-type(3)_&]:block">
        <!-- ... -->
      </div>
</div>
```

I'd strongly suggest to go through the documentation because honestly, it makes my life soooo much easier, I'm 5 times faster than before prototyping now.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

You can use and arbitrary value on the parent, if you conditionally add the class it will show the children like so:

Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/0pCtnVrAh7

```
<!-- hidden -->
<div class="">
  <div class="hidden item">Hey!</div>
</div>

<!-- Show if class "[&_.item]:flex" is added-->
<div class="[&_.item]:flex">
  <div class="hidden item">Hey!</div>
</div>

<!-- Coming soon -->
<div class="group should-show">
  <div class="hidden group-[&.should-show]:block">Hey!</div>
</div>
```

In a future update, hopefully tailwind will allow us to use the group modifier to style based on if the group has an additional class.

Comment: see also the documentation: [Using arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants)

Comment: Nice answer, looking forward to the coming soon approach

Answer (score -3):

Actually, there is.This is a css solution, but it can be achieved in tailwind as well:

```css
.hidden {
display:none
}

.parent .hidden {
display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden">Text that doesn't show up</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="hidden">
    Text is visible
  </div>
</div>
```

html

Comment: This is not tailwind.

Answer (score -4):

**No**. Tailwind is a css framework. To use conditional statements, you can either use Tailwind with javascript or php or any other languages.

Comment: ok thx, i was wondering because there is the group-hover thingy which is kind of in that direction :)

Comment: @nerdess please see my solution its totally possible. Like you say the group-hover is sort of the path youd expect, but currenty it doesnt support to match if the group contains a class like: "group-[.should-show]:block" Adam at tailwind confirmed they are working on this.